# Split one dict into many dicts by startswith condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

The basic case:

I have a dictionary:

```
kwargs = {'scale_a': 10, 'scale_b': 20,
          'shift_a': 15, 'shift_x_and_y': (1,5)}
```

and I want to add them into another dictionary but that dictionary has subdictionaries based on the startstring of `kwargs`. So the result should be:

```
kwds = {'scale': {'a': 10, 'b': 20},
        'shift': {'a': 15, 'x_and_y': (1, 5)}}
```

I'm currently using a longish loop:

```
kwds = {'scale': {}, 'shift': {}}
for i in kwargs:
    splitted = i.split('_', 1)
    try:
        # This will fail if the prefix is not initialized in the dict with a KeyError.
        kwds[splitted[0]][splitted[1]] = kwargs[i]
    except KeyError:
        raise KeyError('Unknown prefix {0} for parameter {1}'
                       ''.format(splitted[0], i))
```

and it is working but I was wondering if one could rewrite that as a dict-comprehension. Or shorten it in some other way. I tried:

```
kwds = {key.split('_', 1)[1]: kwargs[key] for key in kwargs}
```

but that just gives me

```
{'a': 15, 'b': 20, 'x_and_y': (1, 5)}
```

which is not what I want. Is there any way to get the dictionaries inside this dictionary?

---

Some explanation why I want to do it:

I'm using Python3 and I'm writing a function that combines several different functions and since some of the functions are from libraries `numpy`, `astropy` and others I'm using `**kwargs` as parameter and want to distribute the values inside the function.

There are some downsides: Packages alter their API and depending on the functions there might even be the same parameter name twice. So I don't want to hardcode the parameters.

I'll illustrate it with a simple example:

I have several images and I want to combine them. The steps are:

- Scale the images: function takes a callable as parameter and the callable needs some arguments
- Shift the images: callable with parameters
- Stack the images: np.dstack so no arguments needed
- Reject points: again the function takes an arbitary callable and this function wants some input
- Combine images: again a callable but this time it needs no arguments because I want to limit them to numpy functions along axis=2
- Create a deviation image: To see what the variance in the points are. This is another callable that might need some additional parameters, for example np.std could use a `ddof` parameter.

So I thought the most straightforward way to do it would be to expect the user to use keywords that start with `scale_` if they should be passed to the `scale_func` or `shift_` if they should be passed to `shift_func`, etc. This is to avoid that a parameter with the same name for two of these functions would be a problem and allows to handle each of the functions in the most appropriate way (meaning if I only have numpy 1.7 I can only specify the parameters that the function is accepting).

I like this to be fast but I can't figure out how I would do it.

My solution is (rather shortened just to see what I mean):

```
def combine(images, scale_func, shift_func, reject_func, comb_func, dev_func, **kwargs):
    # Prefix should be scale_ for parameters passed to scale_func, shift_ for shift_func, ...

    kwds = {j.split('_', 0)[1]: kwargs[j] for j in kwargs}

    for i in range(len(images)):
        images[i] = shift_func(images[i], **kwds['shift'])
        images[i] = scale_func(images[i], **kwds['scale'])
...
```

The line `kwds[i] = {j.split('_', 1): kwargs[j] for j in kwargs}` is what is not working. Until now I used

```
kwds = {'scale': {}, 'shift': {}, 'reject': {}, 'dev': {}}
for i in kwargs:
    splitted = i.split('_', 1)
    try:
        # This will fail if the prefix is not initialized in the dict with a KeyError.
        kwds[splitted[0]][splitted[1]] = kwargs[i]
    except KeyError:
        raise KeyError('Unknown prefix {0} for parameter {1}'
                       ''.format(splitted[0], i))
```

but that's in my opinion not very pythonic and not very fast. I wondered if one could solve that with a dict comprehension or in some other short and fast way.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's the error you get? `AttributeError: type object 'str' has no attribute 'lsplit'`?

Comment: I added a small example at the top what I want and what I get with the dict comprehension. The ``lsplit`` was just a typo, corrected it.

Comment: I see. My two-liner should work if you don't require invalid keys to raise an exception (they are simply ignored). If you do want to `raise`, then it's not possible to do it in one dict-comp anyway because you can't have statements in comprehensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED: corrected the original answer and added a shorter version.

Not sure what errors you are getting. Probably it's due to `lsplit` (there is only `split` and `rsplit`, no `lsplit`). But in any case I'd suggest factoring some logic out to a helper function:

```
# A helper function which validates and splits a keyword
def split_key(key):
    if not key.startswith(('scale_', 'shift_', 'reject_', 'dev_')):
        raise KeyError('unknown key', key)
    return key.split('_', maxsplit=1)

# Then call it from combine
def combine(..., **kwargs)
    kwds = {}
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        major_key, minor_key = split_key(key)
        kwds.setdefault(major_key, {})[minor_key] = value
    ...
```

This may be a little cleaner (not much, I'm afraid) and easier to understand, with `combine` focusing on the main business and `split_key` taking care of the details (and raising `KeyError` for invalid keys).

If you don't need validation, then the following two-liner will do

```
acceptable = 'scale_', 'shift_', 'reject_', 'dev_'
kwds = {key[:-1]: {k.split('_', 1)[-1]: v for k, v in kwargs.items() if k.startswith(key)} for key in acceptable}
```

though I can't recommend using it if someone will read your code:

Comment: Thank you. I'm actually using helper functions already but in order to make the question minimal I put everything in one function. The dict comprehension is working but rather inefficient since it runs through ``kwargs`` for each ``acceptable`` element and takes almost 7 times longer (in my function) and I hoped I could get a speed improvement as well as a shortened code.

Answer (score 0):

I broke the function down for you and made assumptions on what you tried to do:

Check whether the key starts with one of the special values `['scale_', 'shift_', 'reject_', 'dev_']`

```
[kwargs[j] for j in kwargs if j.startswith(i)] #returns dict value
```

Take the said special value alone and makes it the key to the dict

```
j.split('_', maxsplit=1)[0] # Corrected
```

Builds a dictionary

```
kwds[i] = {j.split('_', maxsplit=1)[0]: kwargs[j] for j in kwargs if j.startswith(i)}
```

Comment: Although I must admit I am not sure why you would even need to perform _j.split('_', maxsplit=1)[0]_ as _i[:-1]_ would have the same end result I think.

Comment: I may have been confusing with the example. I want the key of the dictionary to be the ``[0]`` part of the splitted key but the value of that new key should be another dictionary with the splitted keys ``[1]``-part.